# How to fix error "object has no attribute '_output_tensor_cache'"?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error when fitting a Keras model, defined using its functional API (inheriting from `tf.keras.Model`):

`AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_output_tensor_cache'`

How could I fix it? Here below a minimal piece of code that reproduces it, and then the full stack trace of the error. The error happens when calling `Model.fit()`, even before it gets into the implementation of `Model.__call__()`.

I am using tensorflow-gpu (1.7.0).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


# Using Keras functional API
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,))
        self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)
        self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)

    def __call__(self, inputs, trainig=False):
        y = self.inp(inputs)
        y = self.fc1(y)
        y = self.fc2(y)
        return y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Just a random dataset, to try out the code
    X = np.random.rand(512, 8)
    y = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(512,))

    model = Model()

    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                  metric=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=64, epochs=1, verbose=2, validation_split=.2)
```

Error stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fanta/workspace/wine-quality/minimal.py", line 29, in <module>
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=64, epochs=1, verbose=2, validation_split=.2)
  File "/home/fanta/.local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 1150, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/fanta/.local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 704, in _standardize_user_data
    self._set_inputs(x)
  File "/home/fanta/.local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 880, in _set_inputs
    self._symbolic_set_inputs(inputs, training=training)
  File "/home/fanta/.local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 999, in _symbolic_set_inputs
    outputs = self.call(self.inputs[0], training=training)
  File "/home/fanta/.local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/network.py", line 631, in call
    if cache_key in self._output_tensor_cache:
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_output_tensor_cache'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong in creating a regular model?

```
def createModel():

    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,))
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(inputs)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(outputs)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs,ouptuts)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because used a `Conv2D` layer first and I didn't declare the `input_shape` parameter on my first layer. From [Keras](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d):

> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide the keyword argument input_shape (tuple of integers, does not include the sample axis), e.g. input_shape=(128, 128, 3) for 128x128 RGB pictures in  data_format="channels_last".

This might not help you, but could point you in the right direction or help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading packages helped me:

```
pip install keras==2.0
pip install tensorflow==1.0
```